# Oracle Apex- How to display range of numbers in select list inside LOV

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have to display a select list for years ranging from 2020-2060.

The problem is if i try writing a simple sql using level/rownum it won't take it.

Is there any other way to display the numbers in the range that would then display in the lov?

Comment: What exactly did you try and what was the error?  I've certainly got LOVs that use `connect by level` queries to populate the values.

Comment: The error is wrong number of columns selected: select level
from dual
connect by level <= 2050
order by level desc; Also i want to write this as >2017 and <2050

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Apex, LOV requires two values: display and return. Therefore, you'd

```
SQL> select 2020 + level - 1 as display_value,
  2         2020 + level - 1 as return_value
  3  from dual
  4  connect by level <= 2060 - 2020 + 1
  5  order by 1;

DISPLAY_VALUE RETURN_VALUE
------------- ------------
         2020         2020
         2021         2021
         2022         2022
         2023         2023
<snip>
         2058         2058
         2059         2059
         2060         2060

41 rows selected.
```

So, there's *no problem*.